# How to find n curves between two curves rapidly?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

I have two sets of segments forming two lines. These lines are continuous and they do not cross each other. I would like to obtain the coordinates of the points of n lines between the two original lines. What would be the most efficient algorithm  to do this?

In other word, I would like to find the coordinates of the blue lines in the image given below. The blue lines should be between the black lines without crossing the other blue lines or the black lines.

[image: image with blue and black lines]

Comment: With no other restrictions on your lines, such as smoothness or whatever, just Interpolate points between the two black line segments. E.g. for each point on the x-axis, find A and B, the y values of the lower and upper black lines, and then let your n lines go through points evenly spaced between A and B.

Comment: What about a vertical black line? And what if a black line has two or three y-values for an x-value?

Comment: The vertical line is a problem that my suggestion can't handle, but can with a modification: parametrize the (x,y) positions of each line according to some parameter lambda (e.g. lambda = 0 at one end of the line and 1 at the other). Then for each lambda, interpolate points between the (x,y) coordinates of each line. The second issue, regarding multiple y values for each x value -- do you mean if the line loops around or if it branches? In the former case, the lambda parametrization would work, in the latter they aren't really lines anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will try the parametrisation idea. The black lines do not loop as there is no crossing. But they can "go back". It is a bit difficult to explain. For example, I could have a black line composed of four segments: one from [0,0] to [1,0]. The second from [1,0] to [0.5,1], the third to [2,0], the fourth to [3,0].